# python script using subprocess, redirect ALL output to file

Tags: python, file-io, console, subprocess, cppcheck

I am writing something for static analysis of source code in different languages. As anything has to be open source and callable from command line I now have downloaded one tool per language. So I decided to write a python script listing all source files in a project folder and calling the respective tool.

So part of my code looks like this:

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
from subprocess import call
from pylint.lint import Run as pylint


class Analyser:

    def __init__(self, source=os.getcwd(), logfilename=None):

        # doing initialization stuff
        self.logfilename = logfilename or 'CodeAnalysisReport.log'

        self.listFiles()
        self.analyseFiles()


    def listFiles(self):
    # lists all source files in the specified directory


    def analyseFiles(self):

        self.analysePythons()
        self.analyseCpps()
        self.analyseJss()
        self.analyseJavas()
        self.analyseCs()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    Analyser()
```

Let's have at a look at the C++ files part (I use Cppcheck to analyse those):

```
    def analyseCpps(self):

        for sourcefile in self.files['.cc'] + self.files['.cpp']:
            print '\n'*2, '*'*70, '\n', sourcefile
            call(['C:\\CodeAnalysis\\cppcheck\\cppcheck', '--enable=all', sourcefile])
```

The console output for one of the files (it's just a random downloaded file) is:

```
**********************************************************************
C:\CodeAnalysis\testproject\cpp\BiggestUnInt.cc
Checking C:\CodeAnalysis\testproject\cpp\BiggestUnInt.cc...
[C:\CodeAnalysis\testproject\cpp\BiggestUnInt.cc:18]: (style) The scope of the variable 'oldi' can be reduced.
[C:\CodeAnalysis\testproject\cpp\BiggestUnInt.cc:43]: (style) The scope of the variable 'lastbit' can be reduced.
[C:\CodeAnalysis\testproject\cpp\BiggestUnInt.cc:44]: (style) The scope of the variable 'two_to_power_i' can be reduced.
(information) Cppcheck cannot find all the include files (use --check-config for details)
```

Line 1 and 2 coming from my script, lines 3 to 7 coming from Cppcheck.

And this is what I want to save to my log file, for all the other files too. Everything in one single file.

Of course I have searched SO and found some methods. But none is working completely.

**First try:**

Adding `sys.stdout = open(self.logfilename, 'w')` to my constructor. This makes line 1 and 2 of the above showed output be written to my log file. The rest is still shown on console.

**Second try:**

Additionaly, in `analyseCpps` I use:

`call(['C:\CodeAnalysis\cppcheck\cppcheck', '--enable=all', sourcefile], stdout=sys.stdout)`

This makes my log file to be:

```
Checking C:\CodeAnalysis\testproject\cpp\BiggestUnInt.cc...


********************************************************************** 
C:\CodeAnalysis\testproject\cpp\BiggestUnInt.cc
```

and the console output is:

```
[C:\CodeAnalysis\testproject\cpp\BiggestUnInt.cc:18]: (style) The scope of the variable 'oldi' can be reduced.
[C:\CodeAnalysis\testproject\cpp\BiggestUnInt.cc:43]: (style) The scope of the variable 'lastbit' can be reduced.
[C:\CodeAnalysis\testproject\cpp\BiggestUnInt.cc:44]: (style) The scope of the variable 'two_to_power_i' can be reduced.
```

Not what I want.

**Third try:**

Using `Popen` with `pipe`. `sys.stdout` is back to default.

As preliminary work `analyseCpps` now is:

```
for sourcefile in self.files['.cc'] + self.files['.cpp']:

    print '\n'*2, '*'*70, '\n', sourcefile
    p = subprocess.Popen(['C:\\CodeAnalysis\\cppcheck\\cppcheck', '--enable=all', sourcefile], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p.stdout.read()
```

`p.stdout.read()` shows only the last line of my desired output (line 7 in code box 3)

**Fourth try:**

Using `subprocess.Popen(['C:\CodeAnalysis\cppcheck\cppcheck', '--enable=all', sourcefile], stdout=open(self.logfilename, 'a+'))` just writes the one line `Checking C:\CodeAnalysis\testproject\cpp\BiggestUnInt.cc...` to my logfile, the rest is shown on the console.

**Fifth try:**

Instead of `subprocess.Popen` I use `os.system`, so my calling command is:

`os.system('C:\CodeAnalysis\cppcheck\cppcheck --enable=all %s >> %s' % (sourcefile, self.logfilename))`

This results in the same log file as my fourth try. If I type the same command directly in the windows console the result is the same. So I guess it it is not exactly a python problem but still:

***If it is on the console there must be a way to put it in a file.*** Any ideas?

---

***E D I T***

Foolish me. I'm still a noob so I forgot about the `stderr`. That's where the decisive messages are going to.

So now I have:

```
def analyseCpps(self):

    for sourcefile in self.files['.cc'] + self.files['.cpp']:
        p = subprocess.Popen(['C:\\CodeAnalysis\\cppcheck\\cppcheck', '--enable=all', sourcefile], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        with open(self.logfilename, 'a+') as logfile:
            logfile.write('%s\n%s\n' % ('*'*70, sourcefile))
            for line in p.stderr.readlines():
                logfile.write('%s\n' % line.strip())
```

and it's working fine.

---

***ANOTHER EDIT***

according to Didier's answer:

with `sys.stdout = open(self.logfilename, 'w', 0)` in my constructor:

```
def analyseCpps(self):

    for sourcefile in self.files['.cc'] + self.files['.cpp']:
        print '\n'*2, '*'*70, '\n', sourcefile
        p = subprocess.Popen(['C:\\CodeAnalysis\\cppcheck\\cppcheck', '--enable=all', sourcefile], stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stdout)
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast comments and answers, you are all right.

Comment: related: [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4675728/4279)

Comment: unrelated: do not use `for line in p.stderr.readlines():`, just `for line in p.stderr:` works. Also, you could write `shutil.copyfileobj(p.stderr, logfile)`. Also, you could use `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`. Also, you could [use my answer to redirect stdout at file descriptor level and merge stderr into stdout](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22434262/4279) -- drop `stdout`, `stderr` parameters in this case -- they are handled automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems:

- you should redirect both stdout and stderr
- you should use unbuffered files if you want to mix normal print and the output of launched commands.

Something like this:

```
import sys, subprocess

# Note the 0 here (unbuffered file)
sys.stdout = open("mylog","w",0)

print "Hello"
print "-----"

subprocess.call(["./prog"],stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stdout)
print "-----"
subprocess.call(["./prog"],stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stdout)
print "-----"

print "End"
```

Comment: This is actually pretty cool. I will re-change my implementation.

Comment: @seesharp: it seems fragile to redirect output of every and each subprocess call manually and it fails if some code writes to stdout directly (`os.write(1, b"won't catch me")`). A better alternative is to redirect the output in the code that runs the Python script: `python your_script.py &> log` (bash) or redirect using `os.dup2()` (works on Windows too). See the links in my comments to your question.

Comment: I use Python 2.7 (didn't mention, shame on me) so there is no `contextlib.redirect_stdout()`. Furthermore I decided not to redirect **every** output to a file. As the whole script takes a decent amount of time to run I use print statements to show progress and the subprocesses' outputs are directed directly to my logfile. So far it works, so I will leave it this way but I keep your answer in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1):

You need to redirect stderr too, you can use `STDOUT` or pass the file object to stderr=:

```
from subprocess import check_call,STDOUT
with open("log.txt","w") as f:
     for sourcefile in self.files['.cc'] + self.files['.cpp']:
        check_call(['C:\\CodeAnalysis\\cppcheck\\cppcheck', '--enable=all', sourcefile],
                   stdout=f, stderr=STDOUT)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to redirect `stdout` and `stderr` to a logfile:

```
import subprocess

def analyseCpps(self):
     with open("logfile.txt", "w") as logfile:
         for sourcefile in self.files['.cc'] + self.files['.cpp']:
             print '\n'*2, '*'*70, '\n', sourcefile
             call(['C:\\CodeAnalysis\\cppcheck\\cppcheck',
                   '--enable=all', sourcefile], stdout=logfile,
                   stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

In this example the filename is hardcoded, but you should be able to change that easily (to your `self.logfilename` or similar).

Comment: Well I just realized, the messages go to the stderr and was about to type an answer myself :-). So you are right. I will edit the working code in the answer.